# duplicated history entries at the same timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command-history, terminal-multiplexer

For some time I had an issue with my `history` using GNU `bash` (version 4 and 5) where commands appeared in duplicates. I assumed this was due to the fact that in my `.bashrc` I had the following line:

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

and since I'm using terminal multiplexers (`screen` and/or `tmux`) the above mentioned command gets executed several times (therefore `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` results in `history -a; history -n; history -a; history -n;`

In some situations (especially when doing stuff concomitantly on different panes/windows/frames/buffers) the last command I entered was stored twice or even more often in my `~/.bash_history`. This led to entries like the following:

```
#1596110297
yadm list -a | xargs -t ls -l
yadm list -a | xargs -t ls -l
```

Needless to say, this is pretty annoying.  I hoped I found a fix for the issue by changing the command to `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n` but this did not solve it.

Any ideas why that is the case and what I could do get rid of it?

---

Disclaimer: I posted parts of this question at [grep for lines not after a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604842/grep-for-lines-not-after-a-pattern) (since I thought the above mentioned solution would work and I therefore only wanted to only get rid of the duplicated entries).

Comment: In my Bash setup I don't set anything in the ```PROMPT_COMMAND``` environment variable and history works for me just fine. May I ask what are you trying to accomplish by having ```history -a; history -n``` in ```PROMPT_COMMAND```?

Comment: @Zod They likely want to "share" the history between multiple `bash` sessions running concurrently.

Comment: @Zod: yes, exactly, I'd like to share my history between the different sessions.  I'm aware that alternative solutions exist (e.g. `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r"`, but I'm unsure if that would help.